# Migration from wxHTML to wxWebView in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am trying to replace [wxHTML](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/overview_html.html) with [wxWebView](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_web_view.html) in wxWidgets. I have a problem when trying to get the URL of a clicked hyperlink.
Previously the code was like this:

```
void mywxHtmlWindow::OnLinkClicked( const wxHtmlLinkInfo& link )
{
    ...
    link.GetHref();
    ...
}
```

and now I have:

```
void OnLinkClicked( wxWebViewEvent& evt )
   {
     ...
     evt.GetURL();
     ...
   }
```

The previous result was something like `"myURL"` and the current result is something like `"about:myURL"` and I don't know why there is `"about:"` at the beginning. What should I do to get the same result as before?

Update:

I have set the page source in both cases like below:

```
mBrowser->SetPage( currentPage_, wxString() );
```

and all tags in the page source are something like this:

```
<a href="myURL">clickHere</a>
```

and I want to get `myURL` string when I click on the link.

Update 2:

`myURL` could be any arbitrary string like a hash

```
(e.g. myURL="git-c2b617b1ec4bbaba2201020ec946b037f5935b77").
```

It's not a usual URL like "http://www.google.com".

Comment: why do you changed the control and expect the same behavior? Now here is the question - is `myURL` the same in both cases?

Comment: Hi @Igor, yes 'myURL' is the same in both cases. Only there is "about:" at the begining. I am replacing because I need more functionalities which wxHTML doesn't provide it for me.

Comment: you didn't answer my first question - why do you expect the behaviour to be the same with 2 different things?

Comment: @Igor I updated the question. As I said, I need to get `myURL` string when I click on a link and I don't know another way of getting it in wxWebview.

Comment: what is wx version? OS? WebView backend? Did you check `webview` sample?

Comment: @Igor Yes, I checked the official `webview` sample and get the same result. I don't know why "about" scheme is added. I have the latest version of wxwidget and my OS is Windows 10 and the default backend which I think is IE

Comment: then you need to account for that in your code. It is possible that it is done like this for compatibility with other backends or OS/ports. I don't know. Just for the test - can you check if Edge will handle this the way you want?

Comment: are you trying to open local URL or it is somewhere on the web?

Comment: @Igor I get the URL(as I said, it could be a hash like `xyz`) and then send it to our server on the backend and backend sends back a new source for the page. That's the process. I don't want to open a page on web like www.google.com

Comment: so you just need to account for that in your code. Or try to see where this `about` comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default scheme for Internet Explorer is `about` when you are setting a page source manually. So instead of using `setPage` function, I registered a custom scheme (e.g `myScheme`) like

```
  mBrowser->RegisterHandler( wxSharedPtr<wxWebViewHandler>( new WxHtmlFSHandler( "myScheme" ) ) );
```

load an arbitrary URL like

```
myBrowser->LoadURL( "myScheme:URL.com" );
```

now you have to override the `wxWebViewHandler` class. Something like below:

```
struct WxHtmlFSHandler : public wxWebViewHandler
{
  WxHtmlFSHandler( const wxString& scheme ): wxWebViewHandler( scheme )
  { }

  wxFSFile* GetFile( const wxString& uri ) override
  {
    return ( new wxFSFile( new wxMemoryInputStream( currentPage_.data(), 
    currentPage_.size() ),
    uri, wxT( "text/html" ), currentAnchor_
    #if wxUSE_DATETIME
    , wxDateTime::Now()
    #endif 
    ) );
}
};
```